# I want a workflow that will email attachments

Tags: sharepoint-designer, email, attachments

I'm creating a custom list for a helpdesk app.  I want the user to fill out a form in sharepoint (2010) and add attachments from screenshots, etc.  The workflow should send an email to our helpdesk system with the files attached.  Using sharepoint designer, i can only say yes there is an attachment, but i can't seem to attach the file to the email.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you use Visual Studio instead of SPD to code a solution?

Comment: i will probably have to do that - i wanted to check on a non-code option first.

Comment: Microsoft Flow may work, see the answer here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/226695/18098

Answer (score 5):

Wouldn't you just post a link to the item instead of attach it. I don't know all your requirements, but it seems that that would be a better solution, not only because it is supported OOB, but because it limits overhead with multiple instances of the same file existing in multiple places.

Comment: I'd prefer that, but i'm sending out to a 3rd party outside system and the users may not have sharepoint access.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but there are free codeplex solutions that will do what you are asking.  http://SharePointStuff.Codeplex.com adds a new activity to SharePoint Designer that allows you to send an email with an attachment.  If used on a list item it will send any documents attached to the item or if used on a document library it will send the document in the library.

This solution is deployed as a farm solution and it also requires that outgoing email be setup in your SharePoint farm.

Answer (score 2):

Think you'll need a third party Workflow Activity to do this.

Luckily, there's a pack on Codeplex which offers this: http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/

Comment: That one does not work with SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 2):

As do [Nintex](http://nintex.com) and [K2](http://www.k2.com/en/index.aspx) if you're looking for other robust features.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just send a link in the email to the dispform or edit form of the List item(Helpdesk item)?  The Helpdesk Analyst can then view the entire List item and the various attachments.  Maybe not the requirement but thought it worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an InfoPath Form Template, instead of the native list webpages?
Use the built-in rules in InfoPath Designer to control, where and how to route (workflow) the Form including the Attachments.
All of this using No-Code! :)

You can refer to http://www.sharepoint-videos.com/ for some free instructional videos by Asif Rehmani.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint! We require relevant answers and disclosure of any affiliation with products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines.

Comment: This will allow the entire infopath form with the attachments to be sent via email, but i don't see where to send just the attached files.  Infopath rules do not work on attachments.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Workflow Activity that comes with SharePoint designer does not support this and to the best of my knowledge there are no free workfow activities for SharePoint 2010 who can do this. You may want to have a look at the [Workflow Power Pack](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/send-rich-emails-with-attachments-from.html).

Please note that I have worked on this product so the usual disclaimers apply.

Oh, and if you have the budget then I cannot recommend Nintex Workflow Highly enough.