# Send Attachment in Alert

Tags: alert

How can one send the attachment along with the alert?

Here's my story.  In my email server, I have a bulk-email address.  I create an Active Directory account for that called `Email-Alerts` and use the bulk email address as that user's email.  Simple enough.  Now I log in as that user in the Sharepoint Portal and sign up for whatever alerts that I like.  Now the alert goes out to my bulk-email address and everyone who is on the email list receives the alert without having to sign up individually.

The problem is that the poster has set an alert on an announcements list and attached a document.  We want the document to be sent along with the alert message.

So, how can one send the attachment along with the alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't out of the box. You would need something custom. Using a Workflow via Visual Studio should get you there, easier than manipulating the actual alerting system.

This is what SharePoint is for, to stop email attachments ;)

Comment: I know it can't be done out of the box.  Can you suggest to me a method for custom implementation? (Personally, I don't find fault with the attachments not being sent, but it may be easier to implement a custom solution than to convince my superior that he doesn't want to do it...)

Comment: Ah ok ;) I don't know how to do this off the top of my head, but I would lean towards a workflow vs an alert, I have found customizing the actual alerting system difficult and usually affects the entire farm.

Comment: I'm not opposed to using a workflow - I just need to send the contents of the announcement (when it is newly created) along with the attachment to the bulk email list.  Do you think I can, within the framework of a workflow, do this?  (I'm still learning about workflows)

Comment: You can definitely do it with a Workflow via Visual Studio, not sure about via SharePoint Designer

Comment: Could you edit your answer so I can accept it?  If you have an suggestions about the parameters to use, that would be helpful.  Then I'll mark this solved.

Comment: I think that using a workflow, you can only specify the email address in the workflow - it won't read the address from a user's parameters, such as the Active Directory email field.

Comment: updated. yeah, you'll need to reinvent how users sign up and how the emailing will work.

Comment: I'm looking at it; I don't see how to do this in the UI; in SPD, I don't see any way to add the attachment...  No, see this thread: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17522/i-want-a-workflow-that-will-email-attachments  It can't be done this way with SPD.

Comment: Then Visual studio it is! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Nintex Workflows" to add an attachment to the SharePoint alert sent whenever a new doc is uploaded.