# Getting no e-mail alerts when list attachment has been modified

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, list, alert, attachments

In our SP2010 lists, users who created e-mail alerts will not get notified when the list attachment (here: docx files) has been modified. This is the whether version is enabled or not.

Is this behavior intended, a bug or a mis-configuration in our farm? Maybe someone could test it in their farm:

- Create a list (Task list, custom list, etc.)
- Create notification for that list (All changes, immediate notification)
- Add a list item and attach a docx file
- Open list item and then the attachment
- Edit list attachment in MS Word
- Make a change to the file and Save
- Wait for a couple of minutes if you get an e-Mail regarding that last change

Comment: versioning enabled or not?

Comment: As mentioned above: It does not matter, e-Mails dont came. However, if versioning is enabled, modifing the attachment does create a new version. So SharePoint (somehow) realises that there is a change, but doesn't fire the alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint send the alerts when item's properties got change, But when change is made on the attachment, then even list created new version but for some reason alert logic not recognized it.

In this case, i believe you have to use some king of custom workflow. check this. [Send Attachment in Alert](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77383/send-attachment-in-alert)

or 3rd party options
http://blog.pentalogic.net/2013/03/how-to-configure-email-alerts-to-review-documents-in-sharepoint/