# How can I Send Attachment from SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow along with Email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

How can I Send Attachment from SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow along with Email ?

Here I want to send Document it may be one or more from workflow ,Let me know way to do it.

Comment: Is a link to the document sufficient?

Comment: I have two types of user one is inside tenant and other is anonymous user. For tenant user document link is sufficient but not for external user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want a workflow that will email attachments](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17522/i-want-a-workflow-that-will-email-attachments)

Comment: I have tried to add document link but they have string limit for 255 character. When I am adding multiple document link string will exceed 255 length. @BennySkogberg

Comment: I can show you how to do it for SharePoint Online using Power Automate

Answer (score 0):

**SharePoint 2013 - Send Email With Attachment New**

I have an new version of this workflow action that works with SharePoint 2013. This solution does not work with SharePoint online, you must be able to deploy the solution to central admin. Available at http://www.SPStuffSolutions.com

**SharePoint 2010 - Send Email With Attachment**

I put together this SharePoint Designer workflow activity to allow users to send an email with an attachment in SharePoint 2010. The attachment will be taken from a list item or a document in a document library. Download it here: http://sharepointstuff.codeplex.com/releases/view/66258

Similar [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/17522/21421)

Comment: SPStuffSolutions.com website is for sale. Where can I download "SharePoint 2013 - Send Email With Attachment New"?