# How can i attach pdf to my auto mail that is sending by workflow?

Tags: workflow, send-email

I have got a workflow. The workflow is sending emails. How can i attach pdf document to my auto mail?

Comment: through SharePoint designer i don't think it is possible, you can send attachments using Nintex workflows

Comment: What is Nintex workflow?

Comment: powerful tool for process automation. The intuitive, browser-based drag-and-drop workflow                                    
              https://www.nintex.com/workflow-platform/workflow                                chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/http://nintexdownload.com/sl/supportfiles/NintexWorkflow2013Helpfile.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Not clear if this question is about SharePoint Online or SharePoint on-premise (SP2007-2016). Let me provide you with some options.

1. **SharePoint Designer workflows:** It is not possible to do this with the out-of-the box workflow actions. You can send an email, but not add an attachment.
2. **Nintex Workflow:** If you happen to have [Nintex Workflow](https://www.nintex.com/workflow-platform/workflow) installed in your SharePoint environment then you can use their email facility. It supports attachments.
3. **Microsoft Flow:** If you are using SharePoint Online, or have setup the [Data Gateway](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/gateway-reference/) (to use Flow for SharePoint on-premise), then you can use the Microsoft Flow facility to send emails, including attachments. I wrote a blog post some time ago about how to mix SharePoint Designer workflows and MS Flow to send attachments. [Have a look here](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2016/10/attach-converted-pdf-files-to-email.html).

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't you just post a link to the item instead of attach it. I don't know all your requirements, but it seems that that would be a better solution, not only because it is supported OOB, but because it limits overhead with multiple instances of the same file existing in multiple places.

Comment: The link is not proper for us.

Comment: @Ganesh In my case lots of users that don't have access to the SP Site (some of them external to the company) will need the file. It's just more convenient to attach it to the mail